# Android button does not trigger when in different order in XML file

Tags: android, android-xml

not urgent as I have a work around, however I would really like to understand whether there is a reason for a behaviour I observe when i make the changes below.

I have a simple layout with an EditText and a Button in an XML file.

It displays fine, and as the code below it works fine (triggering onClick)

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/Topic" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AddTopic"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:ems="10" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/AddTopic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick" android:textSize="10dp" android:text="Add Topic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, if I flip the objects around, as below, the button does not trigger - onClick does not run and nothing happens.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:id="@+id/AddTopic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick" android:textSize="10dp" android:text="Add Topic" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/Topic" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AddTopic"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I might be missing something really obvious here, and as I say it doesn't matter in the sense it works in the first structure, but it does matter in the sense I would really like to know why.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: But are button and EditText reversed in gui? Does change something? You are using Eclipse?

Comment: don't really see anything wrong, except for the id declaration: @+id/ is used for declaration, any reference after that should be just @id/

Comment: closed down everything, rebooted my machine and tried again and all works fine :-s

Comment: thanks for the responses - gives me other things to improve :-D

Answer (score 0):

Combining the information posted in the comments, the likely reason is the fact that you mistakenly use `@+id/` when referring to other objects, instead of `@id/`. Specificly `EditText` contains `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AddTopic"`. The `+` sign should only be used when introducing new `id`s.

In the first example it is not harmful for the listener, since the button is declared after the `EditText` and `@+id/` works as should, but in your second example the `id` of the button might be overriden when you declare the `EditText`.

TL;DR: in `EditText`replace `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/AddTopic"` with `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/AddTopic"`. Do this even if you use your "work around".

Comment: For sure you are right - I had made a copy / paste in my frustration and not removed the '+' - will go sort that.  Interestingly though it works now whether the superfluous '+' is in or out.......I think something must have screwed up in Eclipse as after a reboot both code fragments work (although as you say without the '+' is correct)......I will leave the post here though, just in case it should happen to anyone else.

Comment: Strange Indeed!  Maybe the solution is to move to Android Studio :D